# Why does for(var i = 0; i < 600000000000; i++) {} runs so long in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, v8, gecko

I'm using JS for solving tasks on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) now and then. For one of the tasks I had to iterate some 600 billion consecutive numbers. To my surprise, it took about 14 hours in NodeJS.

Just run the snippet below and your browser is stuck for hours (I tried Chrome and Firefox):

```js
console.time('t')
for (var i = 0; i < 600851475143; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('t')
```

For comparison, in Java it runs about 200ms on my machine, 4 seconds if I compute square root of every `i`.

What's happening???

**UPDATE:**
I know that iterating every number was not the right way to solve this particluar PE problem. The question is not about that.

**UPDATE 2:**
I was mistaken about Java. As people correctly pointed out, it just physically can't run this fast. I was just using the wrong number, sorry.

Comment: It's likely that JVM completely eliminates the whole `for` statement since it does not produce any side effects. And V8 is not that smart (yet)

Comment: @zerkms read carefully: JVM runs 4 seconds if I compute square root of current i on every iteration.

Comment: craft your examples carefully - it's an empty body loop in your example.

Comment: are you running this in 32bit or 64bit mode? that's a number that could cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Btw, parameters in Project Euler tasks are selected in a way so that you don't bruteforce but apply some knowledge of math.

Comment: @Andrew Counts: in JS all numbers are IEEE 754, so it does not matter.

Comment: 600 billion operations even if it costed 1 machine cycle each would still take 150 seconds on 4ghz processor, so I doubt anything is happening on Java

Comment: @zerkms that's very true about PE. But my knowledge of math is often not enough, so I brute force just to know the right answer afterwards (I suppose this is also supposed way on PE)

Comment: @AndrewCounts I think I tried it on both 32 and 64. Now using 64.

Comment: @GeorgiyIvankin what task is it actually?

Comment: I doubt you're actually tasked to iterate *that* many numbers.

Comment: @Ja͢ck what if the task is to heat up a room by one degree?

Comment: @zerkms I guess he was asking whether Nodejs is 32bit or 64bit.

Comment: @Leo Deng: how does it change anything? The numbers in JS are floating point IEEE 754 which automatically means that *it does not matter* what architecture you run it on.

Comment: That's problem 3 and YES I know this is not supposed way to solve it.

Comment: @zerkms It's [this problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) in particular.

Comment: @zerkms I know, I was just guessing what he was really referring to. Although I don't think it really matters either.

Comment: @Georgiy Ivankin: the answer was already given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315468/why-does-forvar-i-0-i-600000000000-i-runs-so-long-in-javascript#comment43090822_27315468

Comment: Btw, that's how I solved it when have been solved Euler tasks: http://pastebin.com/3pFukHUQ

Comment: @zerkms Why does than computing every square root of numbers up to this one runs 4 seconds on JVM? Does it understand that we're not using the output? But "understands" not to a full extent so it still spends 4 seconds on something?

Comment: @zerkms I suppose you should delete your last comment ) See PE site ("is it okay to publish my solution elsewhere?")

Comment: @Georgiy Ivankin: "Why does than computing every square root of numbers up to this one runs 4 seconds on JVM? " --- JVM is unbelievably complex toy. It may expand your loop into single or multiple expressions, or do other optimizations. If it runs "not instantly" it does not mean it performed 600851475143 operations.

Comment: @GeorgiyIvankin it will expire in an hour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all both 200ms and 4 seconds are completely ridiculous because your processor can most likely only do up to 4 billion cycles per second (4 GHz), even if one loop iteration costed 1 cycle it would still take at least 150 seconds. However even an empty loop will cost at least 3 cycles per iteration (assuming it's not optimized out), calculating square root adds 5-10 per iteration so you simply didn't do 600 billion square roots in 4 seconds.

And I cannot even reproduce, the following takes forever to run as expected:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (long i = 0; i < 600851475143L; ++i) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
$ javac test.java
$ java -cp . Test
```

Comment: I would actually ask OP to provide bytecode for their both instant and 4 second version, since it's curious indeed.

Comment: I was mistaken about Java (see question update). So it turns out that running through the loop 6 trillion times, with each iteration taking, say, 10 processor cycles, would take ~15000 seconds, which is slightly more than 4 hours, on 4GHz processor. Taking into account that I ran the code on slower processors, everything looks clear now. Thank you.